# how do I read in an int array as a single 3 digit input?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am a highschool java programer (semi-experienced in c++) and I have the assignment of reading in a 3 digit number and outputting it as words. If I could just input each digit seperatly this program would be a breeze, but I must take in all 3 at once, AND do so through breezy swing windows built in, input. Can I just take input in as the int array? must I take it in as a string then parse it some how positon by position into the array, and if so how do I do so?

Comment: please to read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), SO isn't code generator, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, otherwise this question isn't answerable ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accept the number as an int only

then

use the method we use when extracting digits

Hint

> number % 10 is last digit
>   number/10 removes last digit from number

Eg:

> 456%10 = 6
>    456/10 = 45
>
> then 45%10 = 5
>       45/10 = 4
>
> then 4%10 = 4
>    4/10 = 0

Answer (score 1):

Yes, read a line from input as a string, then use `input.split("\\s+")`. This will split at any whitespace char and return a `String[]`. Then you need to parse each array element with `Integer.parseInt`.

On the other hand, if you really need three single-digit `int`s not separated by whitespace, then you can skip the `split` step and just use `int digit = input.charAt(i) - '0'`.

Comment: wait, but a user wouldn't input a white space between each number, for example they would input 234, there is no white space between each number.

Comment: If you are sure you need three one-digit ints, then you can skip the split step and just use `int digit = input.charAt(i) - '0'`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the input from the `JTextField` using `textfield.getText()`
2. Check whether the string contains 3 characters only and are integers.
3. type-cast the string to integer and break down it into `hundred`,`ten` and `ones` place.
4. use `switch-case` and `if-else` to print the specific words.

e.g.,

```
int hundred = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText().substring(0,1));
int ten = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText().substring(1,2));
int ones = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText().substring(2,3));
switch(hundred){
    case 1: System.out.print("One hundred ");
    break;
    case 2: System.out.print("Two hundred ");
    break;
    //similarly for rest of the numbers
}
```

Rest of the logic implement yourself as its a homework.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly implemented:

```
int array[] = new int[3];
String s = //the 3 digit number
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    array[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
```

But I'd even skip the in-between integer array and just use the characters. One reason may be that the numbers don't exactly correspond to their English representations (like "eleven", "twelve"). Switch statements will still be simple with characters.